# Sql query dosen't give correct output

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
SELECT MAX(date)
                    FROM abc
                   WHERE 
                      p_id=p_p_id
                     AND nvl(c_number,0)=nvl(p_c_number,0) 
                     AND nvl(m_number,0)=nvl(p_m_number,0)
                     AND nvl(s_number,0)=nvl(p_s_number,0);
```

> > In the above query p_p_id,p_c_number,p_m_number & p_s_number is passed to this query ,but this query gives the wrong output in certain condition:
> >     in table abc  c_number ,m_number,s_number can be null ,zero or any other value
> >     i want to match c_number if null with p_c_number if null 
> >     but the problem with the above query is ,in case if c_number is null the zero is assigned to c_number and if p_c_number is already zero then it matches null with zero value 
> >     please help ..i am using oracle as rdbms

Comment: ...so use some combination of `is null`? (e.g. `x is null and y is null` -- of course, perhaps Oracle has some trickery to do the above. The `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` can even be used -- `COALESCE(a,b) IS NULL` is true only when `a` and `b` are null -- but just KISS.

Comment: AND ((c_number is null and p_c_number is null ) or (c_number=p_c_number) )...i know this solution but if something different is possible

Comment: @guarav It would be possible to use NVL/NZ with a different sentinel value -- the sentinel value just has to be guaranteed to never be used for valid data. -1 might be appropriate in some cases. I would just rewrite the query though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing each `nvl` condition with the following

```
AND (c_number = p_c_number OR (c_number IS NULL AND p_c_number IS NULL))
```

or as [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst) indicates

```
AND (c_number = p_c_number OR COALESCE(c_number, p_c_number) IS NULL)
```

Comment: @gaurav What are you expecting? Why isn't this applicable?

Comment: @guarave in SQL Server one can *disable* "ANSI NULLS" ... I really hope Oracle doesn't have a similar non-standards semantic hack ;-)

Comment: @phil:I was expecting something different  ,i know the above is more apt thanks for the solution